# structuring a database table

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I created a website for poll, users are meant to register and vote. I created only one table for user's information and commment. below is the columns and rows for the table:

Users:

```
columns:   username password agree_1 reason_1 agree_2 reason_2

rows:      paul     testing   yes     NULL     no      because i don't like it
```

i got an advice from a member here who said i should restructure my tables this way:

```
users
- id
- email
- name

polls
- id
- name

questions
- id
- poll_id
- question
- order

answers
- id
- question_id
- user_id
- answer
```

please which column is the primary key and which is the foreign key. i need to know how one table relates to another. please help. thanks

Comment: @ceejayoz: perhaps to those of us who have been around for a bit; however, I'm guessing the OP is very new.  It's a valid question.

Comment: If someone asks a question, "it should be obvious" is worthless as an answer, and insulting as well.

Answer (score 2):

more often, "**id**" is the **primary key** for that particular table and **table1name_id** is the **foreign key** in that table that relates that table to table1.

e.g. in your example,  id for each table is primary key for that table and `poll_id` is foreign key in `questions` table that **relates "questions" table with poll "table".**

Answer (score 1):

Technically, both approaches are usable.

The question really boils down to one of reuse.  If you intend that this site be used for additional polls, then your colleague is correct in his approach.

However, if this is a single shot type of deal, then what you started with is fine.

Your approach will result in a lot less code / setup.  His will take a bit more time for you to absorb the intricacies of an EAV model; especially with regards to reporting.  Constructing performant queries using an EAV design isn't for the faint of heart.

There is certainly a middle ground.  Namely separate the login information into its own table and create a "poll" answers table that simply has the 4 columns you care about.  This approach would not have any of the flexibility of the EAV approach but meets with standard DB design criteria about structure and is certainly very easy to put together and query from.

And, finally, there is a fourth option: instead of writing your own, just sign up on one of the sites that does free polling.  For example: http://www.micropoll.com/  note: I'm not affiliated with them, nor have I used their product.  It was just a site that popped up in a 2 second google search.

---

**Update** due to comments
Yes, you can perform the simple queries against the structure you originally had.  For example:

1. Count number of users:
   `select count(*) from users`
2. Count number of people who said Yes:
   Yes to agree_1: `select count(*) from users where agree_1 = 'yes'`
   Yes to both: `select count(*) from users where agree_1='yes' and agree_2='yes'`
   Yes to either: `select count(*) from users where agree_1='yes' or agree_2='yes'`
3. Count number of people who said no:
   No to agree_1: `select count(*) from users where agree_1 = 'no'`
   No to both: `select count(*) from users where agree_1='no' and agree_2='no'`
   No to either: `select count(*) from users where agree_1='no' or agree_2='no'`
4. Display
   only comments: `select reason_1, reason_2 from users`
   only yes comments: `select reason_1 from users where agree_1 = 'yes'`
   Comments from either in single column for any yes:
   `select reason_1 from users where agree_1 = 'yes' union all select reason_2 as reason_1 from users where agree_2 = 'yes'`

Comment: Thank you.The site will not be used for additional poll. I want to make it, in such a way that i can achieve the followin:

count number of users,
count number of people who said yes,
count number of people who said no,
 Display only the comments. Can i achieve this with the first above table structure?

Answer (score 0):

using relationships in database keeps data validated and normalized, try to use a structure that doesn't hold redundant data, that man suggested you well enough to get started, all you have to do is use InnoDB engine for tables. 
make id primary in users,poll, questions and answers table and add index to foreign key columns i.e (question_id, poll_id, user_id). 
map

```
    answers.question_id to questions.id 
    questions.poll_id to polls.id
    answers.user_id  to users.id
```

that can be easily done in phpmyadmin's relation view